# How to fetch corresponding td values of table when clicked on Edit button

Tags: jquery

On click of the corresponding edit button , 
How can i fetch the first five  values of td , for example if i click on the first edit

i need to fetch

```
var empid = 123;
var empname = Raj ;
var empphone = 2147483647 ;
var empmail = rajkiran.bh@gmail.com
var depot = Depot1
```

Could you please let me know how to do this

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e)
{


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/1/

Comment: Something like `var tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td'); var empid = tds.eq('1').text();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to get the `tr` that contains the clicked `edit` button and all the related `td` elements. Then you can use `eq()` to retrieve the specific values:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
    var $tds = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
    var empid = $tds.eq(1).text();
    var empname = $tds.eq(2).text();
    var empphone = $tds.eq(3).text();
    var empmail = $tds.eq(4).text();
    var depot = $tds.eq(5).text();

    console.log(empid, empname, empphone, empmail, depot);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/4/)

Comment: @Kiran you should really use classes for `tr` and related `td`s. `.closest('tr')`, `.find('td')` and `.eq(1)` is not flexible solution.

Comment: @Kiran something like `var line = $(this).closest('.line'); var empid = line.find('.empid').text();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to find all of the sibling td elements of the current row with a simple code like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('td').each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/2/

Comment: What about `var empid = `, `var empname = ` and so on?

Comment: It's not hard to implement from here, I think. But the other answer show exactly how to get the values into these variables. In my opinion, it's better to fetch the values into an array or object instead of separate variables...

Comment: To be honest, it was not difficult task from the beginning. Usage of array or a bunch of variables depends on what this data will be used for.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you get it work, but as I can see, it's a data table... So if you have more than 2 rows, (or more than 5 cols, for example 50!) it can be very messy this way... If you use an object, one row will be one inner object, doesn't matter how much data it holds...

Comment: Indeed it is with 50 columns. But table with 50 columns is a mess just as it is. You can set all `td`s text as object properties' values, that's for sure, but you should give unique adequate name for every property. So you should add some data attribute with unique values for every `td`.

Comment: You're right with that... I've just mentioned that one variable for one value is not a good and clear solution for a data-table.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the `siblings` of the `td` element containing the edit button and get all of their texts. I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/5/).

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
    $(this).closest("td").siblings().each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text()); 
    });
});
```